# undefined method `find' for AWS::S3::Bucket:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3

I'm working on implementing an Amazon S3 uploader for my rails project.

I'm trying to access a bucket so that I can assign all the images to a variable and list them.

I keep getting the following error when I try to view my new action in my uploads controller:

```
undefined method `find' for AWS::S3::Bucket:Class
```

Here is my uploads_controller.rb

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
require 'aws/s3'

  def new

    photo_bucket = AWS::S3::Bucket.find('photos')
    @photos = photo_bucket.objects
  end
end
```

The find method is documented here http://amazon.rubyforge.org/.

Any clue as to what is going on here?

Thanks.

Here is my Gemfile:

```
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'rails', '3.2.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 2.2.2'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem "friendly_id", "~> 4.0.1"
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the gem that you're using? Can you show us your Gemfile?

Comment: @RyanBigg Added Gemfile per your request. Looks like the correct gem.

Comment: Hi @Huy, I am getting the same error trying to access a Bucket. I'm on Rails 5 and aws-sdk. undefined method `find' for Aws::S3::Bucket:Class // @songs = Aws::S3::Bucket.find(Musicapp::Application::BUCKET).objects . Did you use aws-sdk or aws-s3?

Comment: @JenLijó this was several years ago. I don't remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use aws-s3 and aws-sdk together since they will conflict with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Works here. What happens if you go to the console and do:

```
require 'aws/s3'
AWS::S3::Bucket.methods.find_all{|m| m=~/find/ }
```

? I'm using aws-s3 0.6.3. If there's still no such method, then perhaps aws-sdk is the culprit? I never used it before.