# Need both aws-sdk and aws-s3 gem, but they conflict with one another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, paperclip

In my previous post [undefined method `find' for AWS::S3::Bucket:Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891891/undefined-method-find-for-awss3bucketclass) we figured out that the Amazon S3 uploader I was creating required aws-s3 gem, but I also had aws-sdk gem installed and those two conflict with each other.

The problem is that I am also using Paperclip and after removing aws-sdk, I found that my app broke.

Is there a workaround? I've search on Stackoverflow but haven't found a good solution yet. Also found this blog, but it seems dated: http://davesouth.org/stories/paperclip-upgrade-breaks-amazon-s3-upload-and-how-to-fix-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the [fog gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/fog) with paperclip successfully to store images on amazon. In fact I found it easier to get working than the AWS gem. You could try swapping out that for aws-sdk.

Comment: Interesting, I did some research and it seems like most people used it in conjunction with CarrierWave. Is this necessary? The documentation for the fog gem is vague when it comes to S3.

Comment: I've not used it with CarrierWave so can't really comment other than I haven't found it necessary!

Answer (score 0):

What version of paperclip and rails are you using?
I came across the same problem but when I upgraded my rails to 3.1.10 and paperclip to 3.4.0, it works just fine. There is no need for any work around.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure that it is good idea, but you could try to downgrade your Paperclip to that version, which is using aws-s3... As far as I can tell [2.4.5](http://rubygems.org/gems/paperclip/versions/2.4.5) is latest.