# AWS::S3::Errors::SignatureDoesNotMatch with Paperclip and Amazon S3 in local dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

**This issue is resolved. Turns out I spent too much time researching the issue since it seemed common and not enough time double checking that my secret access key had copy/pasted correctly in my local env.**

I have read about 20 questions about this and so far none have helped me. I keep getting a SignatureDoesNotMatch exception in my create controller and I can't figure out why.

My class (with minor renaming to "S3" since the project isn't released):

```
class S3File < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :s3_attachment,
    storage: :s3,
    bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    s3_credentials: {
      access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    },
    path: ':id/temp.jpg'
end
```

I define the ENV variables in a .env file and start my server with foreman and I have verified that these values are correct in 'foreman run rails console'.

This has never been working for me, but so far I have tried several paths, I have installed imagemagick, and included the following gems:

```
# rails -v Rails 3.2.2
# ruby -v Ruby 1.9.2p290
gem 'paperclip' # paperclip (3.0.4) in Gemfile.lock
gem 'aws-s3' # aws-s3 (0.6.3) in Gemfile.lock
gem 'aws-sdk' # aws-sdk (1.5.2) in Gemfile.lock
gem 'rmagick' # rmagick (2.13.1) in Gemfile.lock
```

And finally my _form partial looks like:

```
<%= form_for @s3_file do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.file_field :email_attachment %>    
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I will provide more info to anyone who needs it, but at this point I am stumped. Thanks to anyone who is able to help at all.

Answer (score 0):

I've been seeing people trying to use aws-s3 and aws-sdk together but this will [cause conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10896367/167614) because they both use the same module namespacing. I'm not saying this is necessarily your problem, but it's definitely not helping. Paperclip requires aws-sdk, so I would remove aws-s3 from your Gemfile to start. If you're still getting errors, I would recommend adding a debugger right above the has_attached_file line and inspect the ENV variables to make sure they are actually being set.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3 seems to suggest using aws-s3 with paperclip and then I was getting errors about needing aws-sdk.

Comment: It actually depends on which version of Paperclip you are using. They recently changed it from aws-s3 to aws-sdk so you'll have to use the Gem based on which version you are using. Don't know off hand when they made the switch, but if you're using the latest version, then aws-sdk is the way to go.

Comment: This was not the root cause of the issue, but it did allow me to remove a gem that I didn't really need and possibly prevented future issues so thanks.

Comment: Did you try the debugger suggestion too?